# Calling destroy() from final_suspend() results in a crash

Tags: c++, c++20, coroutine

I call `h.destroy()` in `final_suspend` to destroy the coroutine automatically when it finishes execution and then I resume awaiting coroutine (that awaits the task to complete). I found a question about this technique and [an answer explaining why it should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65991264/c-coroutines-is-it-valid-to-call-handle-destroy-from-the-final-suspend-poin/65992656#65992656).

As far as I can see, this technique really works, but not with MSVC 2022 that calls task destructor twice, see the code below:

```
#include <coroutine>
#include <optional>

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <chrono>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

// simple timers

// stored timer tasks
struct timer_task
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point target_time;
    std::coroutine_handle<> handle;
};

// comparator
struct timer_task_before_cmp
{
    bool operator()(const timer_task& left, const timer_task& right) const
    {
        return left.target_time > right.target_time;
    }
};

std::priority_queue<timer_task, std::vector<timer_task>, timer_task_before_cmp> timers;

inline void submit_timer_task(std::coroutine_handle<> handle, std::chrono::nanoseconds timeout)
{
    timers.push(timer_task{ std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + timeout, handle });
}

//template <bool owning>
struct UpdatePromise;

//template <bool owning>
struct UpdateTask
{
    // declare promise type
    using promise_type = UpdatePromise;

    UpdateTask(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle) :
        handle(handle)
    {
        std::cout << "UpdateTask constructor." << std::endl;
    }

    UpdateTask(const UpdateTask&) = delete;

    UpdateTask(UpdateTask&& other) : handle(other.handle)
    {
        std::cout << "UpdateTask move constructor." << std::endl;
    }

    UpdateTask& operator = (const UpdateTask&) = delete;

    UpdateTask& operator = (const UpdateTask&& other)
    {
        handle = other.handle;

        std::cout << "UpdateTask move assignment." << std::endl;

        return *this;
    }

    ~UpdateTask()
    {
        std::cout << "UpdateTask destructor." << std::endl;
    }

    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle;
};

struct UpdatePromise
{
    std::coroutine_handle<> awaiting_coroutine;

    UpdateTask get_return_object();

    std::suspend_never initial_suspend()
    {
        return {};
    }

    void unhandled_exception()
    {
        std::terminate();
    }

    auto final_suspend() noexcept
    {
        // if there is a coroutine that is awaiting on this coroutine resume it
        struct transfer_awaitable
        {
            std::coroutine_handle<> awaiting_coroutine;

            // always stop at final suspend
            bool await_ready() noexcept
            {
                return false;
            }

            std::coroutine_handle<> await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<UpdatePromise> h) noexcept
            {
                // resume awaiting coroutine or if there is no coroutine to resume return special coroutine that do
                // nothing
                std::coroutine_handle<> val = awaiting_coroutine ? awaiting_coroutine : std::noop_coroutine();

                h.destroy();

                return val;
            }

            void await_resume() noexcept {}
        };

        return transfer_awaitable{ awaiting_coroutine };
    }

    void return_void() {}

    // use `co_await std::chrono::seconds{n}` to wait specified amount of time
    auto await_transform(std::chrono::milliseconds d)
    {
        struct timer_awaitable
        {
            std::chrono::milliseconds m_d;

            // always suspend
            bool await_ready()
            {
                return m_d <= std::chrono::milliseconds(0);
            }

            // h is a handler for current coroutine which is suspended
            void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h)
            {
                // submit suspended coroutine to be resumed after timeout
                submit_timer_task(h, m_d);
            }
            void await_resume() {}
        };

        return timer_awaitable{ d };
    }

    // also we can await other UpdateTask<T>
    auto await_transform(UpdateTask& update_task)
    {
        if (!update_task.handle)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("coroutine without promise awaited");
        }

        if (update_task.handle.promise().awaiting_coroutine)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("coroutine already awaited");
        }

        struct task_awaitable
        {
            std::coroutine_handle<UpdatePromise> handle;

            // check if this UpdateTask already has value computed
            bool await_ready()
            {
                return handle.done();
            }

            // h - is a handle to coroutine that calls co_await
            // store coroutine handle to be resumed after computing UpdateTask value
            void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h)
            {
                handle.promise().awaiting_coroutine = h;
            }

            // when ready return value to a consumer
            auto await_resume()
            {
            }
        };

        return task_awaitable{ update_task.handle };
    }
};

inline UpdateTask UpdatePromise::get_return_object()
{
    return { std::coroutine_handle<UpdatePromise>::from_promise(*this) };
}

// timer loop
void loop()
{
    while (!timers.empty())
    {
        auto& timer = timers.top();
        // if it is time to run a coroutine
        if (timer.target_time < std::chrono::steady_clock::now())
        {
            auto handle = timer.handle;
            timers.pop();
            handle.resume();
        }
        else
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_until(timer.target_time);
        }
    }
}

// example

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

UpdateTask TestTimerAwait()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    std::cout << "testTimerAwait started." << std::endl;

    co_await 1s;

    std::cout << "testTimerAwait finished." << std::endl;
}

UpdateTask TestNestedTimerAwait()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    std::cout << "testNestedTimerAwait started." << std::endl;

    auto task = TestTimerAwait();

    co_await 2s;

    //co_await task;

    std::cout << "testNestedTimerAwait finished." << std::endl;
}

// main can't be a coroutine and usually need some sort of looper (io_service or timer loop in this example)
int main()
{
    auto task = TestNestedTimerAwait();

    // execute deferred coroutines
    loop();
}
```

the output with MSVC 2022 is:

```
UpdateTask constructor.
testNestedTimerAwait started.
UpdateTask constructor.
testTimerAwait started.
testTimerAwait finished.
testNestedTimerAwait finished.
UpdateTask destructor.
UpdateTask destructor.
UpdateTask destructor.
```

but the output with GCC 11.1.0 is:

```
UpdateTask constructor.
testNestedTimerAwait started.
UpdateTask constructor.
testTimerAwait started.
testTimerAwait finished.
testNestedTimerAwait finished.
UpdateTask destructor.
UpdateTask destructor.
```

as you can see there is one extra destructor call with MSVC 2022, so the behaviour of the code generated with MSVC 2022 is undefined and it can potentially format your hard drive.

MSVC 2022 version: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.30.30709 for x86

**EDIT9:**

Figured out what happens. The destructor of UpdateTask is called twice with MSVC 2022, see updated code.

**EDIT10:**

From [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines): The coroutine is suspended (its coroutine state is populated with local variables and current suspension point).
awaiter.await_suspend(handle) is called, where handle is the coroutine handle representing the current coroutine. Inside that function, the suspended coroutine state is observable via that handle, and **it's this function's responsibility to schedule it to resume on some executor, or to be destroyed** (returning false counts as scheduling)

Comment: its not clear which code i should compile. the second code works fine, but then I read that you oknow this. THe first code is not complete so am I supposed to merge them somehow?

Comment: @pm100 I am trying to reproduce the crash with the second code example, that is compilable. It also crashes, but I am not sure I did correct changes.

Comment: second code compiles and runs clean for me

Comment: @pm100 do you have MSVC?

Comment: yes vs 2022, compile as c++20

Comment: ok well thats a sure sign of undefined behavior. Let me look

Comment: runes for me in release mode too

Comment: @pm100 do you run in VS with debugger? (it does not crash if I fun from console)

Comment: I think `// always stop at final suspend bool await_ready` is supposed to return `true`. Otherwise it won't ever stop.

Comment: @user7860670 no, `false` means that awaitable object is not ready and `await_suspend` should be called.

Comment: *"no, false means that awaitable object is not ready and await_suspend should be called. "* - exactly

Comment: run both in debugger and from command line, works both times

Comment: @pm100 Figured out what happens. The destructor of UpdateTask is called twice with MSVC 2022, see the updated code.

Comment: Please avoid actually editing the solution into the question. Your last few edits should be added as an answer instead.

Comment: @cigien ok, I'll create a new post next time.

Comment: cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65991264/c-coroutines-is-it-valid-to-call-handle-destroy-from-the-final-suspend-poin

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a compiler bug, that is probably fixed in Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.31.31106.2 for x86, at least now the output is:

```
UpdateTask constructor.
testNestedTimerAwait started.
UpdateTask constructor.
testTimerAwait started.
testTimerAwait finished.
testNestedTimerAwait finished.
UpdateTask destructor.
UpdateTask destructor.
```