# `handle.destroy()` crashes with clang++ 14.0.2 on Mac OS when called in `await_suspend()`

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, c++-coroutine

I have an example of code that works with g++ 12, older clang++ (v14.0.0 on Mac OS with experimental coroutines) and clang++ in unoptimized compilation but crashes with -O2 or -O3 turned on.
The crash happens when calling `destroy` on the handle of the suspended coroutine. The docs on cppreference.com states that when `await_resume` is called:

*the coroutine is suspended (its coroutine state is populated with local variables and current suspension point).
awaiter.await_suspend(handle) is called, where handle is the coroutine handle representing the current coroutine. Inside that function, the suspended coroutine state is observable via that handle, and it's this function's responsibility to schedule it to resume on some executor, **or to be destroyed**.*

My code does just that. It destroys the calling subroutine and resumes another coroutine.
Unfortunately, in MacOS, clang++ 14.0.2 (recent update) makes this code crash but only when -O2 or -O3 are used.

The below code is the minimum code I could build to demonstrate the problem. Note that almost any change will not be able to demonstrate the crash. For example, removing the loop in `main` (the part inside is called only once) will avoid the crash.
The compiler does very aggressive optimization such that running the debugger does not allow to stop in several places that might be useful.

Is this, as I think, a bug in clang++ or am I missing some detail of C++ legalese?

```
#include <iostream>
#if __has_include(<coroutine>)
#include <coroutine>
namespace crt = std;
#else
#include <experimental/coroutine>
namespace crt = std::experimental::coroutines_v1;
#endif

struct Timer {
    auto die_or_return(int t, bool destroy_handle=false)
    {
        struct awaiter {
            bool await_ready() const noexcept { return false; }

            void await_resume() const noexcept {}
            /* https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines states:
             * The coroutine is suspended (its coroutine state is populated with local variables and current suspension point).
             * awaiter.await_suspend(handle) is called, where handle is the coroutine handle representing the current coroutine.
             * Inside that function, the suspended coroutine state is observable via that handle,
             * and it's this function's responsibility to schedule it to resume on some executor,
             * or to be destroyed (returning false counts as scheduling)
             */
            crt::coroutine_handle<> await_suspend(crt::coroutine_handle<> h) noexcept
            {
                auto n = next;
                if (destroy_handle) {
                    h.destroy();
                }
                return n;
            }
            crt::coroutine_handle<> next;
            bool destroy_handle;
        };

        return awaiter{ender, destroy_handle};
    }

    crt::coroutine_handle<> ender = crt::noop_coroutine();
};

inline static bool active{true};

struct [[nodiscard]] autodestruct_task {
    struct promise_type {
        ~promise_type() { active = false; std::cout << "Dying" << std::endl; }
        autodestruct_task get_return_object() noexcept
        {
            return autodestruct_task{crt::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this)};
        }

        crt::suspend_always initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }

        /// If the coroutine does not suspend at the end, its handle is automatically
        /// destroyed.
        crt::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept {return {}; }

        void return_void() noexcept {}

        void unhandled_exception() noexcept { std::terminate(); }
    };

    crt::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle;

    explicit autodestruct_task(crt::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h) noexcept : handle(h) {}

};

autodestruct_task test_death(Timer &timer) {
    co_await timer.die_or_return(0,true);
}

autodestruct_task end_task() {
    std::cout << "Ending" << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

int main() {
    Timer timer;
    timer.ender = end_task().handle;
    auto tsk_handle = test_death(timer).handle;
    while (active && !tsk_handle.done()) {
        std::cout << "Resume" << std::endl;
        tsk_handle();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only wild guess (so not an answer): I see you do "auto n = next;" in await_suspend. I believe it is because "awaiter" object is being destroyed with "h.destroy()" - so you need to store awaiter::next locally in this function. So, my guess is that on the mentioned platform even this "n" is somehow placed in the coroutine frame and it is gone with it. But I cannot confirm it is that or not - because I do not have access to MacOS and this code works on my systems. Try to replace "auto n = next;" with "auto* n = new crt::coro...handle<>(next);" - if it works - then probably I am right.

Comment: @PiotrNycz You are right that you cannot access the variables of the awaiter (next) after the "h.destroy()". However  as shown in the examples of coroutines at the web page mentioned in my example, you should copy what you want to have available to a local variable, which "auto n = next;" does. The variable is now alive in a register or on the stack. When calling "h.destroy()" it should most likely be pushed on the stack. So it is legal code. If the compiler optimizes out the reading of 'next' before the destroy() and reads it only at the return statement, then it's a bug in the compiler.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. That maybe this compiler has a bug. I probably should express it in a more straightforward way

Comment: @PiotrNycz an alternative to allocating memory just for the handle is to just add the word `thread_local` in front of `auto n = next;`. It does avoid the crash. It looks like an acceptable workaround, but like all workaround of this kind, it's a hack and it does not mean the bug could not re-appear under some modified compilation flags.

Comment: I am afraid - you can only issue the bug here https://bugs.llvm.org/ and stick with the current workarounds for some time

Comment: @PiotrNycz i have reported the bug. The LLVM core team person responsible for coroutines replied the bug does not appear in their version but only in the Apple fork. So I have reported it there but nobody has answered yet. https://github.com/apple/llvm-project/issues/6724